# PNG8 Rendering in ArcGIS Runtime .NET?

Tags: geoserver, wmts, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have Geoserver serving cached layers (WMTS) as PNG and PNG8. I am able to render my layers using the runtime in PNG without an issue, but every time I try and render in PNG8 I just get a blank screen despite serving an existing cache for both PNG and PNG8. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can work around this? I am looking an expanding my layers and want to keep the rendering as light as possible, thus why I want to use PNG8.

Comment: Does the PNG8 tile look correct when you retrieve it by url with your browser?

Comment: Yep, when I preview my layers in Geoserver in PNG8 in my browser they load beautifully.

Comment: Did you try setting `PreferredImageFormat` after creating the layer? https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference/html/P_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Mapping_WmtsLayer_PreferredImageFormat.htm

Comment: Hi Kirk. I did:
        <esri:MapView x:Name="mapView" >
            <esri:Map MinScale="559082264" MaxScale="136495" >
                <!-- MinScale="559082264"  MaxScale="272989" Level 11  MaxScale="1091956" Zoom Level 9      MaxScale="2183915" -  Zoom Level 8 -->
                <!--http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&amp;tilematrixset=EPSG:4326-->
                <esri:WmtsLayer Source="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&amp;tilematrixset=EPSG:4326" PreferredImageFormat="Png8" LayerId="Workspace:Layer"/>

Comment: I think this might be a bug.  I've posted here on Esri's site: https://community.esri.com/message/816490-wmts-tileimageformat-list-not-populating-correctly-for-wmts-layer

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was just doing something wrong. I've tried on all versions of the 100 runtime with no luck.